# Can't recognize double amp in xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, entity

I have next string named `str`:

```
...
<div data-bind="visible: enablePost()==false && serverParam()=='', text:serverMessage"></div>
...
```

Before to make `XDocument.Load(str)` I had wrapped this in `<root>` tag and append special entities options in beginning:

```
private const string Dtd = @"<!DOCTYPE a [<!ENTITY amp ""&#38;""> <!ENTITY nbsp ""&#160;"">]>";
```

And it works well if I use in html text one ampersand. But when parser meets two adjacent ampersands, it crashes on it. What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: yes, and I've found solution

Comment: just replace '&&' "&#38;&#38;" and thats all